# Insert a number of figures in a document

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

There are the `NumChars`, `NumPages` and `NumWords` fields in Microsoft Word. 
One can use them to insert corresponding values into a document. 
Is it possible to insert a number of figures in a document without using macros?

Answer (score 1):

Only if you put field codes in that would allow you to count the figures. You would probably have to adjust for any figures in headers/footers manually.

For example, if you inserted the following nested field for every figure

{ SET f { SEQ f } }

(all the {} have to be the special field brace characters that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on WIndows Word)

then you can display the figure count using { REF f } or { f }. { REF f } will actually display the last value of the bookmark f that Word calculated, so it would be important to select the entire document (ctrl-A) and update all the field codes (F9) a cople of times to make sure that happens.